# Dynamically assign function to threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

Want to spawn some threads and assign function to each of them later on in a loop.

Spawning the threads with

```
var threadList = new List<Thread>();
for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
    threadList.Add(new Thread(() => { }));
}
```

Now in a loop want to assign function to the threads

```
for (int index = 0; index < names.Length; index++)
{
    string tempName = names[index];
    //check which thread is available
    //assign a function to the first available thread
}
```

How do i do it?

If i am using a threadpool:
how do i get notified when all the threads are done? how do i stop the threadpool to perform any qction in queue?

Comment: Check out how other people tried to implement "thread pool" i.e. in this SO question [Code for a simple thread pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435668/code-for-a-simple-thread-pool-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use ThreadPool instead?

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(myMethod);
```

This will assign your methods to an available thread which will be freed up when done.

Comment: thanks for the input..
however isn't there disadvantages of ThreadPool?
how can i use a method in ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem where the parameter is not of object type?

Comment: how do i get notified when all the threads are done?
how do i stop the threadpool to perform any qction in queue?