# Multi threaded Windows service to process Windows Message Queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

This is my first attempt at writing a Windows service.

This windows service has to process 2 windows message Queues.

Each Message Queue should have there own thread, but I can't seem to get the Architecture in Place.

I followed this [Windows Service to run constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly/4865893#4865893) which allowed me to create one thread in which I am Processing one Queue.

So this is my service class:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc) { Name = "Address Calculator Thread", IsBackground = true };
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void WorkerThreadFunc()
    {
        _addressCalculator = new GACAddressCalculator();

        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            _addressCalculator.StartAddressCalculation();
        }
    }



    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        if (!_thread.Join(5000))
        { // give the thread 5 seconds to stop
            _thread.Abort();
        }
    }
```

In My `GACAddressCalculator.StartAddressCalculation()` I am creating a Queue Processor Object which looks like this:

```
    public void StartAddressCalculation()
    {
        try
        {
            var googleQueue = new GISGoogleQueue("VehMonLogGISGoogle", 1, _gacLogger, 1);
            googleQueue.ProccessMessageQueue();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

And this is `GISGoogleQueue`:

```
public class GISGoogleQueue : BaseMessageQueue
{


    public GISGoogleQueue(string queueName, int threadCount, GACLogger logger, int messagesPerThread)
        : base(queueName, threadCount, logger, messagesPerThread)
    {
    }

    public override void ProccessMessageQueue()
    {
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(base.QueueName))
        {
            _logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Information, string.Format("Queue '{0}' doesn't exist", this.QueueName));
            return;
        }

        var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(QueueName);
        var myVehMonLog = new VehMonLog();
        var o = new Object();
        var arrTypes = new Type[2];
        arrTypes[0] = myVehMonLog.GetType();
        arrTypes[1] = o.GetType();
        messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(arrTypes);

        using (var pool = new Pool(ThreadCount))
        {

            // Infinite loop to process all messages in Queue
            for (; ; )
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < MessagesPerThread; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (pool.TaskCount() >= MessagesPerThread) ; // Stop execution until Tasks in pool have been executed


                        var message = messageQueue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0)); // TimeOut for message reading from Queue, set to 5 minutes, Will throw exception after 5 mins

                        if (message != null) // Check if message is not Null
                        {
                            var monLog = (VehMonLog)message.Body;
                            pool.QueueTask(() => ProcessMessageFromQueue(monLog)); // Add to Tasks list in Pool
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Now this works fine for 1 Message queue, but if I want to process another message Queue it won't happen as I have an infinite loop in the `ProccessMessageQueue` method.

I want to execute each Queue in a separate thread.

I think I am making a mistake in `WorkerThreadFunc()`, I have to somehow start two threads from there or in the `OnStart()`.

Also if you have any tips on how to improve this service would be great.

By the way I am using the Pool Class from this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/436552/1910735 for the thread Pool inside `ProccessMessageQueue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest changing your service class as follows (comments below):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc)
              {
                  Name = "Run Constantly Thread",
                  IsBackground = true
              };
    _thread.Start();
}

GISGoogleQueue _googleQueue1;
GISGoogleQueue _googleQueue2;
private void WorkerThreadFunc()
{
    // This thread is exclusively used to keep the service running.
    // As such, there's no real need for a while loop here.  Create
    // the necessary objects, start them, wait for shutdown, and
    // cleanup.
    _googleQueue1 = new GISGoogleQueue(...);
    _googleQueue1.Start();
    _googleQueue2 = new GISGoogleQueue(...);
    _googleQueue2.Start();

    _shutdownEvent.WaitOne();  // infinite wait

    _googleQueue1.Shutdown();
    _googleQueue2.Shutdown();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _shutdownEvent.Set();
    if (!_thread.Join(5000))
    {
        // give the thread 5 seconds to stop
        _thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

I'm ignoring your `GACAddressCalculator`.  From what you showed, it appeared to be a thin wrapper around `GISGoogleQueue`.  Obviously, if it actually does something that you didn't show, it'll need to be factored back in.

Notice that two `GISGoogleQueue` objects were created in the `WorkerThreadFunc()`.  So let's next look at how to create those objects to achieve the appropriate threading model.

```
public class GISGoogleQueue : BaseMessageQueue
{
    System.Threading.Thread _thread;
    System.Threading.ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent;

    public GISGoogleQueue(string queueName, int threadCount, GACLogger logger, int messagesPerThread)
         : base(queueName, threadCount, logger, messagesPerThread)
    {
        // Let this class wrap a thread object.  Create it here.
        _thread = new Thread(RunMessageQueueFunc()
                  {
                      Name = "Run Message Queue Thread " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                      IsBackground = true
                  };
        _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public Start()
    {
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public Shutdown()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        if (!_thread.Join(5000))
        {
            // give the thread 5 seconds to stop
            _thread.Abort();
        }
    }

    private void RunMessageQueueFunc()
    {
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(base.QueueName))
        {
            _logger.LogMessage(MessageType.Information, string.Format("Queue '{0}' doesn't exist", this.QueueName));
            return;
        }

        var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(QueueName);
        var myVehMonLog = new VehMonLog();
        var o = new Object();
        var arrTypes = new Type[2];
        arrTypes[0] = myVehMonLog.GetType();
        arrTypes[1] = o.GetType();
        messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(arrTypes);

        using (var pool = new Pool(ThreadCount))
        {
            // Here's where we'll wait for the shutdown event to occur.
            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < MessagesPerThread; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Stop execution until Tasks in pool have been executed
                        while (pool.TaskCount() >= MessagesPerThread) ;

                        // TimeOut for message reading from Queue, set to 5 minutes, Will throw exception after 5 mins
                        var message = messageQueue.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0));

                        if (message != null) // Check if message is not Null
                        {
                            var monLog = (VehMonLog)message.Body;
                            pool.QueueTask(() => ProcessMessageFromQueue(monLog)); // Add to Tasks list in Pool
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach centers around using a `Thread` object wrapped by the `GISGoogleQueue` class.  For each `GISGoogleQueue` object you create, you get a wrapped thread that will do the work once `Start()` is called on the `GISGoogleQueue` object.

A couple of points.  In the `RunMessageQueueFunc()`, you're checking to see if the name of the queue exists.  If it doesn't, the function exits.  ***IF*** that happens, the thread exits, too.  The point is that you may wish to do that check earlier in the process.  Just a thought.

Second, note that your infinite loop has been replaced by a check against the `_shutdownEvent` object.  That way, the loop will stop when the service shuts down.  For timeliness, you'll need to make sure that a complete pass through the loop doesn't take too long.  Otherwise, you may end up aborting the thread 5 seconds after shutdown.  The abort is only there to make sure things are torn down, but should be avoided if possible.

I know a lot of people will prefer using the `Task` class to do things like this.  It appears that you are inside `RunMessageQueueFunc()`.  But for threads that run for the duration of the process, I think the `Task` class is the wrong choice because it ties up threads in the thread pool.  To me, that what the `Thread` class is build for.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think you have a typo in RunMessageQueueFunc():  while (!_shutdownEvent.Wait(0)) I think it should be: !_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel.ForEach like this;

```
 Parallel.ForEach(queueItems, ProcessQueue); //this will process each queue item in a separate thread


 private void ProcessQueue(QueueItem queue)
 {
     //your processing logic       
 }
```