# VS2005 c# multi threading: how to launch 10 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the best way to launch 10 threads like in a for loop for a process intensive method. A code example would be very helpful.

```
for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++) //10 threads are intended.
{
    LongRunningMethod();
}
```

Comment: Please note that you are creating 11 threads here. Just a detail.

Answer (score 5):

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Comment: Just make sure you have enough MaxThreads in there (10, in this case), otherwise some of your threads will wait in the queue.

Comment: The thread pool is shared between your app and the CLR library. There are scenarios where using it might have negative effect on the app.

Comment: We can't really tell what LongRunningMethod is doing, but given the name it is probably not optimal to use thread pool threads for this.

Comment: And you can even have more than 10 thread but only 10 will run at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you don't want to use the thread pool, just create and start a new thread.

```
new Thread( delegate() { LongRunningMethod(); } ).Start();
```

Comment: Using thread pool threads for long running jobs can have implications on your app and the CLR performance.

Comment: Reasons for not using the thread pool are described under "Limitations of Using the Thread Pool"

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Multithreading-Thread-Pool.aspx

Comment: The ThreadPool recycle's threads, there-by avoiding the overhead of creating new threads.  As Franci says, the main reason to avoid it is for long-running background threads--in which case spawning a new thread will incur the initial overhead, but leave the pool threads free for short-job's to use.

Comment: The OP mentions VS2005, aka C#2. So a lambda isn't helpful.

Comment: Ah forgot that, changed to C# delegate syntax

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) to schedule your job on a thread in the thread pool or create a new explicit [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) instance for that work. You can read more about the various ways to create threads at the [MSDN Threading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx).

Which approach you use can have certain implications on the performance and behavior of your app and the CLR. For more details, read [When to use thread pool in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145304/when-to-use-thread-pool-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Action as a delegate to create a new thread for each long running method call.

```
Action newThread = new Action(LongRunningMethod);

// Call Async which is a new thread
newThread.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Action with no template is only in .NET 3.5, for .NET 2.0 you have to declare a delegate

```
public delegate void NoParametersMethod();

NoParametersMethodnewThread = new NoParametersMethod(LongRunningMethod);

// Call Async which is a new thread
newThread.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Comment: Delegate.BeginInvoke() utitizes the Remoting Messaging system and incurs a fair overhead, using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem avoids this overhead

Answer (score 1):

The answers and comments here may seem a bit divided, this is because the first thing to do here is to check if your `LongRunningMethod()` is suited for the Threadpool. If it is then using the ThreadPool is the best choice (low overhead, some rudimentary loadbalancing).

Otherwise, use Thread and ThreadStart:

```
ThreadStart starter = new ThreadStart(LongRun);

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // 10 threads are intended, note the i=1
{    
    Thread t = new Thread(starter);
    t.Start();
}
```

Note 1: that there also exists a ParameterizedThreadStart class.
Note 2: You can't scale this to i < 100 or something, you need to keep a lid on the max number of threads. The pool already does that.

From MSDN:

#### When Not to Use Thread Pool Threads

There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:

- You require a foreground thread.
- You require a thread to have a particular
  priority.
- You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from starting.
- You need to place threads into a single-threaded apartment. All ThreadPool threads are in the multithreaded apartment.
- You need to have a stable identity associated with the thread, or to dedicate a thread to a task.

Note that MSDN does not say what a 'long period of time' is. I'll take a stab at it and say that when your task takes >= 0.5 second you might start looking at separate threads. The overhead of creating a Thread becomes insignificant. But it depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this ...

```
var threads    = new List<Thread>();
var numThreads = 10;

for( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ )
{
  threads.Add( new Thread( () => DoWork() ) );
  threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
  threads[i].Start();
}
```