# Do I need to call Close() on a ManualResetEvent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose, waithandle, resource-leak

I've been reading up on .NET Threading and was working on some code that uses a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).  I have found lots of code samples on the internet.  However, when reading the documentation for [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx), I saw the following:

> WaitHandle implements the Dispose
>   pattern. See Implementing Finalize and
>   Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged
>   Resources.

None of the samples seem to call .Close() on the ManualResetEvent objects they create, *even the nice [Recursion and Concurrency](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/01/31/7357135.aspx) article from the pfxteam blog* (***Edit*** - this has a using block I has missed).  Is this just example oversight, or not needed?  I am curious because a WaitHandle "encapsulates operating system–specific objects," so there could easily be a resource leak.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, if an object implements `IDisposable` it is doing so for a reason and you should call `Dispose` (or `Close`, as the case may be). In the example you site, the ManualResetEvent is wrapped inside a `using` statement, which will "automatically" handle calling `Dispose`. In this case, `Close` is synonymous with `Dispose` (which is true in most `IDisposable` implementations that provide a `Close` method).

The code from the example:

```
using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
   ...
}
```

expands to

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
try
{
   ...
}
finally
{
   ((IDispoable)mre).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I was recently forwarded an excerpt from [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800963) By Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari.  On page 834, in **Chapter 21: Threading** there is a section talking about this.

> **Disposing Wait Handles**
>
> Once you’ve finished with a wait
>   handle, you can call its **Close** method
>   to release the operating system
>   resource. Alternatively, you can
>   simply drop all references to the wait
>   handle and allow the garbage collector
>   to do the job for you sometime later
>   (wait handles implement the disposal
>   pattern whereby the finalizer calls
>   **Close**). This is one of the few
>   scenarios where relying on this backup
>   is (arguably) acceptable, because wait
>   handles have a light OS burden
>   (asynchronous delegates rely on
>   exactly this mechanism to release
>   their **IAsyncResult’s** wait handle).
>
> Wait handles are released
>   automatically when an application
>   domain unloads.

Comment: The documentation for WaitHandle.Finalize says there is no longer an implementation from .NET 2.0. You can also see this with a decompiler. WaitHandle no longer has a finalizer. I don't know why, but any abandoned WaitHandle will leak it seems. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291974(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Djof: Even though `WaitHandle` no longer has a `Finalize` method, I don't think that means they leak. Instead, cleanup is handled within a `SafeHandle` to which a `WaitHandle` holds a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The Close is handled inside ManualResetEvent's Dispose, and that's called by the 'using' statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice the code

```
 using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
 {
    // Process the left child asynchronously
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        Process(tree.Left, action);
        mre.Set();
    });

    // Process current node and right child synchronously
    action(tree.Data);
    Process(tree.Right, action);

    // Wait for the left child
    mre.WaitOne();
}
```

uses the 'using' keyword. This automatically calls the dispose method when finished even if the code throws an exception.

Comment: I totally missed the using block when looking over that code.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've used `ManualResetEvent` a lot and don't think I've ever used it inside a single method--it's always an instance field of a class.  Therefore `using()` often does not apply.

If you have a class instance field that is an instance of `ManualResetEvent`, make your class implement `IDisposable` and in your `Dispose()` method call `ManualResetEvent.Close()`.  Then in all usages of your class, you need to use `using()` or make the containing class implement `IDisposable` and repeat, and repeat...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `ManualResetEvent` with anonymous methods then it's obviously useful. But as  Sam mentioned they can often be passed around into workers, and then set and closed.

So I would say it depends on the context of how you are using it - [the MSDN WaitHandle.WaitAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) code sample has a good example of what I mean.

Here's an example based on the MSDN sample of how creating the WaitHandles with a `using` statement would exception:

> **System.ObjectDisposedException**
>   "Safe handle has been closed"

```
const int threads = 25;

void ManualWaitHandle()
{
    ManualResetEvent[] manualEvents = new ManualResetEvent[threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        using (ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ManualWaitHandleThread), new FileState("filename", manualResetEvent));
            manualEvents[i] = manualResetEvent;
        }
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualEvents);
}

void ManualWaitHandleThread(object state)
{
    FileState filestate = (FileState) state; 
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    filestate.ManualEvent.Set();
}

class FileState
{
    public string Filename { get;set; }
    public ManualResetEvent ManualEvent { get; set; }

    public FileState(string fileName, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)
    {
        Filename = fileName;
        ManualEvent = manualEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: That appears to be an example where .Close() is not called on the ManualResetEvent, and there is no using block.  I don't think the worker can close it after a set because the main thread is using it in the WaitHandle.WaitAll(manualEvents) call.

Comment: @Kevin my point was the array of WaitHandles can't be wrapped in an using clause when created as *I think* they'd be closed when they arrived, I'd need to check though.