# Multithreading vs. Multi-Instancing - Which to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Will it be a big difference between this two scenarious:

1. one instance of application creates 100 threads to process some jobs
2. 10 instances of the same application creates 10 threads each to process jobs (total 100)

The number of threads in both cases will be the same. Is it some performance or any type of improvements of one over another?

> Instance - is for example console application, so in second case it
>   will be 10 console application running. each of application has it's
>   own folder.

Comment: 3. Don't create 100 simultaneously-active threads unless you're on a Cray with a whole bunch of processors.

Comment: Do your processes need to communicate?

Comment: Apolagize for the incorrect answer( which is deleted). I tested the above scenario and I found the single process multi threaded application is actually faster than multi process application. Will try to myself understand the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to clarify the requirements: all threads are independent, performing the same task (send data to ftp server but each thread send to different server), no thread synchronization is required, each thread has it's own data.
As I understand from performance point of view 1st approach is better. But with second you have better control over the processes which also can be helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A thread uses less resources than a process so theoretically option 1 would be "better". However, you probably won't notice much difference between the two, because 100 separate threads *or* processes all running simultaneously and fighting for the same O/S resources is pretty much guaranteed to grind your system to a halt.

I would choose option 3 - one process containing a fairly small thread pool. That way, some jobs will execute simultaneously and the rest will queue up and wait their turn. This approach also scales well if a very large number of jobs are going to be run.

See the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) class, *or preferably*, one of the many higher-level abstractions on top of it (e.g. the [task library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx), or even plain old [asynchronous delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx)).

Comment: By O/S you mean OS(Operating System) right ?

Comment: @VickyDev That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 has (at least) the following overheads:

- More process objects
- More per process static memory
- More instances of the CLR and jitted code
- Context switches need to switch the address space (very expensive)
- Less opportunities to share application data structures
- You need cross-process communication. Simple method calls become IPC operations
- More work for you
- More opportunities for bugs (IPC communication, fork bombs, ...)
- Worse debuggability
- No built-in load-balancing through the thread-pool
- Harder and more error-prone synchronization. Less built-in stuff and slower

Why would you choose (2) if you can choose (1)? There are valid reasons, but those are rather special:

- You need to be able to tolerate arbitrary memory corruption. This is not normal the case (not at all!)
- You need the ability to kill threads. This cannot be done reliably inside the CLR for single threads. But you could do it cooperatively which is usually the better option anyway
- Your threads need to run under different users and such. This almost never happens.

**In general, the less processes the better.**

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why IPC is harder to debug? Also what about load-balancing?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing, but in most cases Option 1 will have the best performance and will be the easiest to work with.
To give you a more complete answer I would need to know the following:

- Are the 100 Threads all performing the same task?
- Are the 100 Threads accessing the same data?
- Are the tasks handled by the threads going to have natural down time (waiting for another process to finish or a resource to become available)?
- Are the tasks handled by the threads going to all try to access a limited resource (like the hard disk or network card)?
- How many simultaneous threads can your computer handle at one time (for example a 4 core processor with Hyper-Threading could handle 8 threads, a 4 core processor without Hyper-Threading could handle 4 threads)?
- What happens if something goes wrong on a thread?  Does the process crash, is the thread restarted?

If the threads are all performing the same task, keeping them together will make is easier on the end user and later developers, as everything is in one place.

If the threads are all accessing the same data then keeping them in the same process will allow you to share that data between threads (though watch out for race conditions when changing the data) and reduce the memory foot print.  You also might be able to team up the threads to access data from the same blocks, so everything can be cached on the CPU, reducing the effect of memory latency, though this is not something I would recommend attempting.

Since many of the answers are giving advice on how to implement your project, knowing if each thread is designed to fully use the CPU all the time it is running or if these are background tasks which do a small amount of work before going back to sleep will help us make suggestions correct for your situation.

Knowing what hardware the process will be running on will help us provide suggestions correct for your situation.

If a thread fails, what happens?  If a thread fails once a day, is a user required to intervene, stop the process, and restart it?  If so then any unsaved work done on the other threads would be lost.  In this case, having each thread run in its own process would give you the benefit of only losing the process which failed.

---

Christian Hayter's option 3 makes sense, but is not always relevant with C#.
If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx), it states:

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can use the CLR Hosting API to schedule many managed threads against the same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread between different operating system threads.

Basically this means the .Net framework will pool your threads if it feels like it would be a good idea.  This is more likely to happen if your processes is using more threads, while the number of total threads would probably stay pretty similar between multi-threaded processes.  As a result I would expect the 1 process, 100 threads solution to use fewer total threads then the 10 processes, 10 threads each (something like 10 to 40, but you would have to check).

That being said, the framework will be guessing, so in some cases Thread Pools will be a better option.  Be sure to read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) first, as there are some cases where Thread Pools should not be used.  A quick tutorial on Pools can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.100).aspx).  There is also a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145304/when-to-use-thread-pool-in-c) which discuses when to use Thread Pools.

---

If you provide more information then I will attempt to give a more accurate answer.  Otherwise option 1 (and possibly option 3) are the better choices in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be a big difference. There are pros and cons in each approach:

- Memory consumption. Obviously, each of 10 processes will require
  creation of their own address space, etc.
- Simplicity of communication/synchronization. While it is relatively easy to
  communicate/synchronize threads (you can use critical sections, which
  is one of the most efficient ways), it will be harder to do between
  processes. In your scenario with 10 processes and 10 threads you'll
  have to do both ways.
- Crashes. If one of the threads in process does
  something wrong, the whole process dies.

I personally would prefer one process/many threads. However, it really depends on the task.

Comment: I tested the actual scenario and found multiple processes are slower. You are right. I deleted my incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Such an odd question, hard to find a practical application..But I would imagine option 1 would be better from a performance standpoint. With running 10 instances of the same app, there will be more work being done it would seem. (cleanup, registering, console open, ect)

Edit* 
Because with option 1, you could que up the work and let the threadque handle the load.